# How to check for element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to run some code only when a particular element in the DOM (img tag) exists, if not then I want to run some other code. Below is what I have till now.

**Original Code:**

```
 ed.on('blur', function (e) {
        var iFrame = $('iframe');

        $("img[src*='blob']", iFrame.contents()).each(function (i) {
            var originalUrl = $(this).prop('src');
            var that = $(this);
            // SOME CODE

           );
        });
```

**Below is what I want**

```
ed.on('blur', function (e) {
    var iFrame = $('iframe');
******If ( img[src*='blob' exists in the iFrame )********
    $("img[src*='blob']", iFrame.contents()).each(function (i) {
        var originalUrl = $(this).prop('src');
        var that = $(this);
        // SOME CODE
       );
    }   
    else
    {
       // Do something else
    }
});
```

So basically if I cannot find  `$("img[src*='blob']"` in the iframe I want to run some other code. Please guide me.

Comment: so select it and check the length....

Comment: Why is a dupe?? OP is using contents as a context selector.... The dupe should be how to check if an element exists...

Comment: @epascarello: What do you mean? I am confused. So below answers won't work for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of just doing the each, store it into a variable and check the length.

```
var imgs = $("img[src*='blob']", iFrame.contents());
//var imgs = iFrame.contents().find("img[src*='blob']"); //how I would write it
if (imgs.length) {
    imgs.each(...)
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Out of all the answers, only your answer worked. Thank You sir. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check the number of elements in the jQuery object ([jQuery.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/)):

```
if($('img[src*="blob"]').length > 0) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: How will this code access the iFrame contents?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img[src*='blob']").length > 0
```